# Java prepareStatement setting

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have prepare Statement like this:

```
WHERE  TRADE_DATE >= TRUNC(add_months(current_date,-12))
```

But I want to have it like this:

```
WHERE  TRADE_DATE >= TRUNC(?)
```

And set the value later like this:

```
query.setString(1,"add_months(current_date,-12)");
```

or

```
query.setString(1,"trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')");
```

However, I got error saying

```
inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can't you just pass in the `Date` value with `setDate` instead? I don't think you're going to be able to do it the way you're trying here...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to build your template statement using string concatenation etc, and record the parameters you wish to insert alongside that (in an array of objects?).

Then iterate through each one and perform your `setString()` etc. You can't insert arbitrary SQL using `PreparedStatement` (it would effectively defeat one of `PreparedStatement`'s benefits, which is to restrict the SQL construction to customising parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a java.sql.Date calculated with Calendar as SQL did.

Otherwise - 
if the expressions to fill in can be enumerated, you can use an SQL CASE expression switching on a choice number:

```
CASE ? WHEN 1 THEN add_months(current_date,-12)
       WHEN 2 THEN trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')
END

query.setInt(choice);
```

Maybe something for a stored procedure.